# Efficient way of running multiple successive for loops in R?

Tags: r, for-loop

I am trying to run several for loops in succession in R.   I hope this simplified example of the kind of thing I am trying to do provides enough information, and that the question is relevant/interesting enough to a general audience.

Essentially, I have a pool of individuals (here represented by the 26 LETTERS and saved in a vector called 'ids').  I start with 2 of them randomly selected (called 'ids1') and run a for loop (here 5 times as defined by 'runs').  Those letters not picked get put into another vector called 'ids.left1'.

The first thing going on in the for loop in this example is that I am just randomly picking one of the letters five times.   I am storing the result of this in another vector called result1.  In this example I'm also storing those letters not used in another vector called 'otherresult1'.  (My real-world reason for doing this would be using loops containing several different processes, not just these two).

```
set.seed(123)

#Initializing
ids<-LETTERS[1:26]
runs<-5


#1st time
result1 <- vector("list",runs)
otherresult1 <- vector("list",runs)  
ids1<-sample(ids,2)
ids.left1<-setdiff(ids,ids1)

for (i in 1:runs) {               
  picked1<-sample(ids1, 1)
  result1[[i]] <- picked1 
  otherresult1[[i]] <- setdiff(ids1,picked1)
}

result1x<-unlist(result1)  #[1] "H" "T" "T" "H" "T"
```

The above is trivial.   What I am trying to do next is to add an extra letter (randomly selected) to the pool (so we now have 3) and run the for loop again for the same number of times (5).  I also want to store the now 23 letters not being used in a vector (ids.left2) and also store the results of this loop in result2.  Those not selected get stored in otherresult2.

```
#2nd time
result2 <- vector("list",runs) 
otherresult2 <- vector("list",runs)  
ids2<-c(ids1, sample(ids.left1,1))
ids.left2<-setdiff(ids,ids2)

for (i in 1:runs) {               
  picked2<- sample(ids2, 1)  
  result2[[i]] <- picked2
  otherresult2[[i]] <- setdiff(ids2,picked2)
}

result2x<-unlist(result2)  #[1] "T" "T" "X" "T" "X"
```

This is repeated again.  Another letter is added (so we now have 4), and the same for loop is run 5 times, and the results stored again in another vector.  Those not used again get stored in otherresult3.

```
#3rd time
result3 <- vector("list",runs) 
otherresult3 <- vector("list",runs)  
ids3<-c(ids2, sample(ids.left2,1))

for (i in 1:runs) {               
 picked3 <- sample(ids3, 1)
 result3[[i]] <- picked3
 otherresult3[[i]] <- setdiff(ids3,picked3)
}

result3x<-unlist(result3)  #[1]  "H" "O" "H" "H" "T"
```

This is just putting the results all together.

```
#putting results together

results.final <- c(result1x,result2x,result3x)
results.final  #[1] "H" "T" "T" "H" "T" "T" "T" "X" "T" "X" "H" "O" "H" "H" "T"


unlist(otherresult1) #[1] "T" "H" "H" "T" "H"
unlist(otherresult2)  #[1] "H" "X" "H" "X" "H" "T" "H" "X" "H" "T"
unlist(otherresult3) #[1] "T" "X" "O" "H" "T" "X" "T" "X" "O" "T" "X" "O" "H" "X" "O"
```

This is all pretty easy when I am only running the for loop 3 times.  However, if I wanted to do the same thing (adding in one individual into a pool of individuals) 1000 times, it would be crazy to manually write the code.  (Obviously, I wouldn't be using letters if I ran it 1000 times but some other identifier).

My question is therefore, is it possible to more efficiently code these successive for loops?

EDIT:  I added in another process in the for-loop (the result being stored in 'otherresult' vector) to try and make this more realistic.

Comment: You can replace the `for` loop(s) with `replicate(runs, sample(...))`

Comment: in this example I have stripped down everything going on in the for loop to just the sampling.  In reality, there would be a number of things going on, the results of which would be stored in other vectors - replicate probably wouldn't work then ???

Comment: The answer will generally involve figuring how (if possible) to vectorize as much as possible. But unless your example accurately reflects what you're trying to do, all of our attempts to help will simply be met by the response "that works for my example but not my real data".

Comment: @joran I take the point! Though I was trying to avoid the problem of basically asking people to do my work/coding for me.  I will try to add a bit to my example to make it more realistic.

Comment: Don't feel too bad. It's extremely hard to help people vectorize code in any meaningfully general way. You basically have to have people help you with some extremely specific examples, and after a while you develop a sense for it.

Comment: if I'm understanding correctly, is the issue that you cannot write the code at all, not just vectorize it? (though that is always desired when it doesn't hurt code readability)

Comment: I think if I am trying to boil down my issue is that I am trying to write code for N successive for loops, each time adding in an extra individual to the pool of potential individuals.   I can store the results of each for loop in vectors and combine them at the end of the final loop, but was wondering if I am missing a more elegant way of doing this.    I realize that my quirk of needing an extra individual added each for loop makes this example not that generalizable.

Comment: This is a perfect example of where recursion should be used. I'm at work so can't do it now but maybe I'll do it tonight, if you're still interested comment here and let me know

Comment: @hedgedandlevered thanks for the comment.  Yes, I'd be very interested in hearing about recursion.  Thanks for thinking about this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A perfect time to use recursion

```
recCount <- 1 #which recursive iteration we are in
allLetters <- LETTERS[1:26]
endPoint <- 6 #after how many recursions do we stop
runs <- 5 
recEx <- function(resultList,otherResultList,
                  inLetters,outLetters,
                  recCount)
{
  newLetter <- sample(inLetters,ifelse(recCount==1,2,1)) #pick a letter, 2 if this is the first run
  outLetters <- c(outLetters,newLetter) #add this letter to our pool of usable letters
  inLetters <- inLetters[inLetters!=newLetter] #subtract this letter from the total pool
  excludedList <- includedList <- list() #initialize the lists we will add to
  for (i in 1:runs) {               
    picked1<-sample(outLetters, 1)
    includedList[[i]] <- picked1 
    excludedList[[i]] <- setdiff(outLetters,picked1)
  }
  if(recCount == endPoint) return(list(c(resultList,list(includedList)), #if we're done
                                       c(otherResultList,list(excludedList)))) else
  return(recEx(c(resultList,list(includedList)), #pass in our results so far, and add the "included" list onto the end
               c(otherResultList,list(excludedList)), #same with the "excluded" list
               inLetters,outLetters,recCount+1))
}

finalResult <- recEx(list(),list(),allLetters,NULL,1)


    > finalResult
[[1]]#1 is for your final results, #2 is for the excluded results
[[1]][[1]]# 1 through 6 are your 6 iterations, with 2 through 7 letters in each iteration
[[1]][[1]][[1]] #1 through 5 are your 5 runs
[1] "H"

[[1]][[1]][[2]]
[1] "T"

[[1]][[1]][[3]]
[1] "T"

[[1]][[1]][[4]]
[1] "H"

[[1]][[1]][[5]]
[1] "T"


[[1]][[2]]
[[1]][[2]][[1]]
[1] "T"

[[1]][[2]][[2]]
[1] "T"

[[1]][[2]][[3]]
[1] "X"

[[1]][[2]][[4]]
[1] "T"

[[1]][[2]][[5]]
[1] "X"


[[1]][[3]]
[[1]][[3]][[1]]
[1] "H"

[[1]][[3]][[2]]
[1] "N"

[[1]][[3]][[3]]
[1] "H"

[[1]][[3]][[4]]
[1] "H"

[[1]][[3]][[5]]
[1] "T"


[[1]][[4]]
[[1]][[4]][[1]]
[1] "Y"

[[1]][[4]][[2]]
[1] "N"

[[1]][[4]][[3]]
[1] "N"

[[1]][[4]][[4]]
[1] "Y"

[[1]][[4]][[5]]
[1] "N"


[[1]][[5]]
[[1]][[5]][[1]]
[1] "N"

[[1]][[5]][[2]]
[1] "N"

[[1]][[5]][[3]]
[1] "T"

[[1]][[5]][[4]]
[1] "H"

[[1]][[5]][[5]]
[1] "Q"


[[1]][[6]]
[[1]][[6]][[1]]
[1] "Y"

[[1]][[6]][[2]]
[1] "Q"

[[1]][[6]][[3]]
[1] "H"

[[1]][[6]][[4]]
[1] "N"

[[1]][[6]][[5]]
[1] "Q"



[[2]] #your excluded letters
[[2]][[1]]
[[2]][[1]][[1]]
[1] "T"

[[2]][[1]][[2]]
[1] "H"

[[2]][[1]][[3]]
[1] "H"

[[2]][[1]][[4]]
[1] "T"

[[2]][[1]][[5]]
[1] "H"


[[2]][[2]]
[[2]][[2]][[1]]
[1] "H" "X"

[[2]][[2]][[2]]
[1] "H" "X"

[[2]][[2]][[3]]
[1] "H" "T"

[[2]][[2]][[4]]
[1] "H" "X"

[[2]][[2]][[5]]
[1] "H" "T"


[[2]][[3]]
[[2]][[3]][[1]]
[1] "T" "X" "N"

[[2]][[3]][[2]]
[1] "H" "T" "X"

[[2]][[3]][[3]]
[1] "T" "X" "N"

[[2]][[3]][[4]]
[1] "T" "X" "N"

[[2]][[3]][[5]]
[1] "H" "X" "N"


[[2]][[4]]
[[2]][[4]][[1]]
[1] "H" "T" "X" "N"

[[2]][[4]][[2]]
[1] "H" "T" "X" "Y"

[[2]][[4]][[3]]
[1] "H" "T" "X" "Y"

[[2]][[4]][[4]]
[1] "H" "T" "X" "N"

[[2]][[4]][[5]]
[1] "H" "T" "X" "Y"


[[2]][[5]]
[[2]][[5]][[1]]
[1] "H" "T" "X" "Y" "Q"

[[2]][[5]][[2]]
[1] "H" "T" "X" "Y" "Q"

[[2]][[5]][[3]]
[1] "H" "X" "N" "Y" "Q"

[[2]][[5]][[4]]
[1] "T" "X" "N" "Y" "Q"

[[2]][[5]][[5]]
[1] "H" "T" "X" "N" "Y"


[[2]][[6]]
[[2]][[6]][[1]]
[1] "H" "T" "X" "N" "Q" "V"

[[2]][[6]][[2]]
[1] "H" "T" "X" "N" "Y" "V"

[[2]][[6]][[3]]
[1] "T" "X" "N" "Y" "Q" "V"

[[2]][[6]][[4]]
[1] "H" "T" "X" "Y" "Q" "V"

[[2]][[6]][[5]]
[1] "H" "T" "X" "N" "Y" "V"
```

This isn't the best structure for results imo, but this is as you specified. Unpacking these lists is trivial though

Comment: thanks very much for this.  I didn't consider that I was essentially looking at recursion.  This means more learning for me - thanks.   This works great.

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
set.seed(123)

#Initializing
ids =LETTERS[1:26]
runs=5



result1 = list()
temp = sample(ids,2)
j=1
results = c()

while(j<6) {


ids.left = ids[!(ids%in%temp)]

for(i in 1:runs){
  result1[[i]] = sample(temp,1)
}

temp = c(temp, sample(ids.left,1))

j=j+1
results = c(results, unlist(result1))
}

results # [1] "H" "T" "T" "H" "T" "T" "T" "X" "T" "X" "H" "O" "H" "H" "T" "Y" "O" "O" "Y" "O" "O" "O" "T" "H" "Q"
```